# Is there a way to use "arrayormula" to do calculations on muptible rows?

Tags: google-sheets

So' im trying to make my sheet to calculate hours worked on a project. I would like to use arrayormula since I need to insert rows in between projects.

I have made the following formula, but it only calculates the first row of data.

=ArrayFormula((IF(C2="";"";MOD(C2-B2;1)*24)))

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GPKZuufT0H3sLB2lv2MZqVHirtvCoByWfZUljV-1Cbg/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggesttions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula((IF(C2:C="";;MOD(C2:C-B2:B;1)*24)))
```